# Content Broker database - Using non relational database with DXA

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, broker

Like DXA works with JSON, a database like MongoDB (non-relational) would give a better performance than a DB2 database.

Could we use a database non relational for the Broker?

Comment: An old colleague of mine once built a broker using Apache Jackrabbit. I don't think he was motivated by performance problems though. Even further back, Tridion themselves had a broker based on Software AG's Tamino database. Anything is possible. It's software. Dropping ACID with MongoDB....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDL doesn't currently support any non-relational database for the broker, so the answer is "it depends".

If you want to you *can* use a different storage layer altogether by extending the deployer to interact with that database instead of Tridion's own Broker DB. You will lose the rest of the Tridion CD API (including dynamic linking, publication mapping, any sort of Component Presentation Assembly, etc) and you'll have to implement that yourself.

So... you're basically on your own to do it. Is it possible? Sure it is, I've demoed it with MongoDB back in 2013.

Oh yeah, and it is also not supported by SDL.

Putting my serious hat back on. It seems that your reasoning to use a different database system is performance related (based on your wording). A much easier way to improve performance is to implement Tridion and Application caching. DXA and Tridion CIL already come with client-side caching (time-based) and it is amazing how much turning this on can actually impact your system's performance. Depending on your editor profiles, you could probably get away with something like 15 minutes caching on the app (meaning editors would potentially have to wait up to 15 minutes to see a change they published to the live site).

Tridion Content Service Caching also makes a huge difference, and for this you need to make sure you implement invalidation correctly - see https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-7E728735-073B-4827-AABE-B45592CFF36D for details.

Comment: The use of the storage layer extension point is supported, but indeed you loose support on the Content Delivery APIs as you will have to implement them yourself. Fun to see how we can come up with a similar type of answer which still is very different.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you break the 'chain' from CMS->BROKER DB->ContentDelivery(DXA) when replacing the middle storage layer with a custom storage solution. NoSql may perform better on its own, but the total solution will not be faster than an in-memory cached website. See Nunos comment.

Technical consequences are:

- Implementing storage extension for support for NoSQL
- Implement own data providers to mimic the SDL UDP API platform.

Business consequences are (to name a few):

- Implementing costs are higher
- Unsupported by vendor, you have to support and maintain it yourself
- Upgrades will be troublesome

To summarize: will the (minimal) DB performance gain really deliver you better/faster sites and does it justifies the extra risks and costs involved?

Comment: Interesting point you raise here Guus, I'm now wondering if the question is actually asked correctly. Maybe the question should not be leading (can we use NoSql), but address the problem (how do I make DXA perform better)? @Guskermitt can you **edit** your question and provide background information on the reason for this question?

Answer (score 3):

DXA is just an implementation of Tridion and therefore is bound to the prerequisites of it, see https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7.1.1/GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659

From there you can follow the prerequisites of the Tridion Content Delivery databases which are:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP1 (Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 SP2 (Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition)
- Oracle Database 12c patch set 12.1.0.2 (Enterprise Edition)
- Oracle Database 11g Release 2 patch set 11.2.0.4 (Enterprise Edition)
- Microsoft Azure SQL Database
- AWS RDS-MSSQL 2016

See also https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-AD4CC402-9F80-4338-9DFD-BFBF61BBBABC

So to summarize, because Tridion currently does not support non relational databases for their Content Delivery environment, it is simply not possible (unless you want to proceed in an unsupported setup of course).